# How to read a list when writing to a Byte Array

Tags: c#, list, arrays, google-play-services

I am using C#, Google Play Game Services, and Unity. I need to be able to write from a list which contains floats, to a byte array, then read them again in another method. I can make it so it stores the floats in the list of course (I can see it in my output as well), but when I print the Count of the list when trying to write to the byte array it tells me my list Count is zero... Its odd because when I check the list anywhere else outside this method it gives me the correct size. What am I doing wrong?

I have added the portions of code from the two other classes where I am adding items to the list. Again, I already know it successfully is added to the list, it just wont give me the correction count when im in the ToByte method.

Match Data Class----

```
private List<float> mRuneTypes = new List<float>();

 public byte[] ToBytes() { //here is where I am trying to write to the mem stream

    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(memStream);

    w.Write(Header); //writes header ID to memory

    w.Write(mRuneTypes.Count); //this shows up as zero but everywhere else as 4

    for (int i =0; i<4; i++) {


        w.Write(mRuneTypes[i]); //i get an index out of bounds since list is empty?


        Debug.Log( "Writing the color val is: " + mRuneTypes[i]);


    }

    networkStatus = "has wrote to mem"; //just something for me to check

    w.Close();

    byte[] buf = memStream.GetBuffer();

    memStream.Close();

    return buf;
}


public void AddRuneTypes(float runeIntDesignation) { //this is where the values are passed and added to the list

    mRuneTypes.Add(runeIntDesignation);

    Debug.Log ("the before tobyte count is : " + mRuneTypes.Count); //gives the correct count of 4... why isnt it the same in ToByte[]??

}
```

/////from TurnedBasedGameOp Class

```
public void passRunes(float runeIntDesignation) {
    //sent runes are passed from the block selector to this class to matchdatarunes

    mMatchData.AddRuneTypes (runeIntDesignation);
    print ("rune type of " + runeIntDesignation + " has been added");
}
```

/////from Block Selection Class

```
this.GetComponent<TurnedBasedGameOrganizer>().passRunes(selectedBlocks[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeteorCode>().runeIntDesignation);//this sends the runes selected to the TurnedBasedGameOp Class above this code is contained in a larger For loop which doesnt need to be included
```

Comment: Paste the code where you fill data for an instance of this class and where you call the `ToBytes()` method, so we could try to find the error.

Comment: The code aded last edition seems ok. I see no wrong stuff in there. So next thing is to check where you use `ToBytes()`. Are you using that method in the same instance of Match Data Class that the instance you used to fill data?

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet the ***mRuneTypes*** list was empty, I think you need paste the code which you fill the list data so that we could try to find out the reason why it doesn't work.

And for the ***for*** loop statement, don't use the magic number "4", please using the following code instead yours, so the out of index exception will be gone.

```
for(int i=0; i<mRuneTypes.count; i++){
     // Do your logic code.
 }
```

Wish it will be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This right here is bad...

```
for (int i =0; i < 4; i++)
```

The reason it's bad is because right from the get-go, you're presuming that `mRuneTypes` contains a collection of items, but from the code that I can see, all that you've done is initialized a collection, you haven't populated it.

If you're attempting to iterate through every item within the list, either use the `foreach` statement or use the `for` statement that will only increment up to the total number of items within the collection:

```
int i = 0; i < mRuneTypes.Count; i++`.
```

Another tip that may help you is this little helper method whilst you're debugging...

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T Dump<T>(this T tObject)
    {
        tObject.GetType()
               .GetProperties()
               .Where(property => property.GetValue(tObject) != null)
               .Select(property => string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(tObject)))
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        return tObject;
    }
}
```

At the end of any object just add `.Dump()` and observe the output to see the properties of the object...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. It had something to do with the turnbasedgameorganizer class that i was using to send data to the match data runes class. I just ended up combining them.